# How can I get specific fields from within fields in a JSON file?

Tags: json, command-line, command-line-arguments, jq

I have a file called test that I create by fetching info with cURL like this:

```
curl "https://example.com/public?command=getInfo" > test | python -m json.tool > test
```

and it results in something like this:

```
{
    "A_B": {
        "Field1": "0.36564104",
        "Field2": "0.00000580",
        "Field3": "0.00000558",
        "Field4": 177,
        "Field5": "0"
    },
    "B_A": {
        "Field1": "19.02374743",
        "Field2": "0.00049000",
        "Field3": "0.00047179",
        "Field4": 253,
        "Field5": "0"
    },
    "A_C": {
        "Field1": "19.02374743",
        "Field2": "0.00049000",
        "Field3": "0.00047179",
        "Field4": 253,
        "Field5": "0"
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to get from A_B and A_C Field2 and Field5. Therefore I tried using an AWK live editor but so far the best I've managed is

```
-F "[, ]+" '/A_B/{print $2,$5}'
```

Which is to say, I haven't made any real progress, and of course, it doesn't work.

My goal is to save into two files called test2 and test3 which would look something like this:

test2:

```
A_B: 0.00000580
A_C: 0.00049000
```

test3:

```
A_B: 0
A_C: 0
```

containing the values of Field2 in test2 and Field5 in test3, but so far, I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -r '"A_B: \(.A_B["Field2"])", "A_C: \(.A_C["Field2"])"' test > test2
```

Explanation: Command

```
jq -r '.A_B["Field2"]' test
```

extracts the value `0.00000580` of `Field2` of `A_B` and `"A_B: \(…)"` adds the literal string `A_B:` as prefix. The same happens with the `A_C` field which is printed on the next line. The output is redirected to file `test2`.

The equivalent command for `field5` and output file `test3` is

```
jq -r '"A_B: \(.A_B["Field5"])", "A_C: \(.A_C["Field5"])"' test > test3
```

Comment: You can also use the .x.y notation in cases like `.A_B["Field2"]`, i.e. `.A_B.Field2`

Comment: It worked exactly as I needed it to work, thank you very much,  @Freddy!
This was exactly what I've been looking for, again, thank you very very much!
And also a big thanks to @peak for the further simplification of the code!
Thanks to both of you!